# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Redmine Wrong Ruby Version

Tags: ruby, redmine

Finished upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, where I have a Redmine installation, after finish upgrading, Redmine stopped.

When I try to access I get the error:

```
Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.9 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Backtrace of the error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `map!'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `materialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:101:in `block in definition_method'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:365:in `activate_gem'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:529:in `running_bundler'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:382:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

When I run bundle install, it looks like everything is ok:

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem redmine_crm (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
Using activesupport 5.2.3
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.10.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.10
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.12.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 5.2.3
Using rack 2.2.3
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 5.2.3
Using nio4r 2.5.8
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
Using actioncable 5.2.3
Using globalid 0.5.2
Using activejob 5.2.3
Using mini_mime 1.0.3
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 5.2.3
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using thor 1.1.0
Using railties 5.2.3
Using actionpack-xml_parser 2.0.1
Using activemodel 5.2.3
Using arel 9.0.0
Using activerecord 5.2.3
Using mimemagic 0.3.10
Using marcel 0.3.3
Using activestorage 5.2.3
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using bundler 2.2.25
Using css_parser 1.10.0
Using csv 3.0.9
Using htmlentities 4.3.4
Using liquid 2.6.3
Using mysql2 0.5.3
Using net-ldap 0.16.3
Using ruby-openid 2.3.0
Using rack-openid 1.4.2
Using sprockets 4.0.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Using rails 5.2.3
Using rbpdf-font 1.19.1
Using rbpdf 1.19.8
Using redcarpet 3.4.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Using redmine_crm 0.0.55
Using request_store 1.0.5
Using rmagick 2.16.0
Using roadie 3.5.1
Using roadie-rails 1.3.0
Using rouge 3.3.0
Bundle complete! 29 Gemfile dependencies, 62 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups 'development', 'teste', 'test', 'postgresql' and 'sqlite' were not installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

If i check the gem that it's missing:

```
* concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
        Summary: Modern concurrency tools for Ruby. Inspired by Erlang, Clojure, Scala, Haskell, F#, C#, Java, and classic concurrency patterns.
        Homepage: http://www.concurrent-ruby.com
        Source Code: https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby
        Changelog: https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
        Path: /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9
```

So it looks like that Redmine it's looking for the gems in the ruby 2.7.0 folder and I have the gems in the 2.5.0 folder.

If this is the problem, what should I do?
Force the redmine to use the ruby 2.5, looks like he best approach?
Or force the gems to be installed in the 2.7 version, if so, how to do this? Remove the 2.5 and if I run the bundle install it does the job?

Current GemFile.Lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activejob (= 5.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionpack-xml_parser (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    actionview (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
    activerecord (5.2.3)
      activemodel (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    capybara (2.18.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    crass (1.0.6)
    css_parser (1.10.0)
      addressable
    csv (3.0.9)
    docile (1.1.5)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    globalid (0.5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    json (2.5.1)
    liquid (2.6.3)
    loofah (2.12.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1)
      rake
    mini_mime (1.0.3)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    mocha (1.13.0)
    mysql2 (0.5.3)
    net-ldap (0.16.3)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.10.10)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (3.12.6)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-openid (1.4.2)
      rack (>= 1.1.0)
      ruby-openid (>= 2.1.8)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.3)
      actioncable (= 5.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activejob (= 5.2.3)
      activemodel (= 5.2.3)
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)
      activestorage (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.3)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rbpdf (1.19.8)
      htmlentities
      rbpdf-font (~> 1.19.0)
    rbpdf-font (1.19.1)
    redcarpet (3.4.0)
    redmine_crm (0.0.55)
      liquid (< 2.6.4)
      rails
      rubyzip
    request_store (1.0.5)
    rmagick (2.16.0)
    roadie (3.5.1)
      css_parser (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    roadie-rails (1.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.3)
      roadie (~> 3.1)
    rouge (3.3.0)
    ruby-openid (2.3.0)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    simplecov (0.14.1)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      json (>= 1.8, < 3)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.2)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.1.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tzinfo (1.2.9)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    yard (0.9.26)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  actionpack-xml_parser
  bundler (>= 1.5.0)
  capybara (~> 2.13)
  csv (~> 3.0.1)
  i18n (~> 0.7.0)
  mail (~> 2.7.1)
  mimemagic
  mini_mime (~> 1.0.1)
  mocha
  mysql2 (~> 0.5.0)
  net-ldap (~> 0.16.0)
  nokogiri (~> 1.10.0)
  puma (~> 3.7)
  rack-openid
  rails (= 5.2.3)
  rails-dom-testing
  rbpdf (~> 1.19.6)
  redcarpet (~> 3.4.0)
  redmine_crm
  request_store (= 1.0.5)
  rmagick (~> 2.16.0)
  roadie-rails (~> 1.3.0)
  rouge (~> 3.3.0)
  ruby-openid (~> 2.3.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  simplecov (~> 0.14.1)
  tzinfo-data
  yard

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.25
```

If I query the ruby version:

```
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]
```

But I can see that I have the 2.7 installed as well.

RVM Info:

```
ruby-2.5.0:

  system:
    uname:        "Linux AtomServer 5.4.0-80-generic #90-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 9 22:49:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    name:         "Ubuntu"
    version:      "20.04"
    architecture: "x86_64"
    bash:         "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:          " => not installed"
    remote_path:  "ubuntu/20.04/x86_64"

  rvm:
    version:      "1.29.11 (latest)"
    updated:      "6 months 20 days 7 hours 36 minutes 33 seconds ago"
    path:         "/usr/share/rvm"
    autolibs:     "[4] Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X)."

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.5.0p0"
    date:         "2017-12-25"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2017-12-25 revision 61468"
    full_version: "ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0"
    ruby:         "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin:/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/bin:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/jnap/.dotnet/tools:/usr/share/rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0:/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error found the solution.

So after upgrading, everything got messed up, wrong versions, so I did this:

1. sudo gem install bundler (the bundler version was an old one)
2. bundle install (with the new version of the bundler, installed the gems in the correct dir/version)

After this steps, I got a new error, about missing manifest.js, so I did another two things:

1. mkdir -p app/assets/config && echo '{}' > app/assets/config/manifest.js
2. Create a new Gemfile.local with this content: gem "sprockets", "~> 3.7.2"
3. bundle update

After this, got everything working.